# jQuery validate not working even (asking as last resort)

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am having trouble validating my form with the jQuery validate plugin. It is not validating client-side.

HTML:

```
<form name="addNoteForm" class="form-horizontal" id="addNoteForm" action="addOrderNote.php?OrderID=<?php echo $OrderID; ?> method="POST">                                
    <div class="control-group <?php echo!empty($onNotesError) ? 'error' : ''; ?>">
        <label class="control-label"><strong>Notes (Max 500 chars):</strong></label>
        <div class="controls">
            <textarea id="addNotesNotes" name="onNotes" rows="10" cols="300"><?php echo!empty($onNotes) ? $onNotes : ''; ?></textarea>
            <?php if (!empty($onNotesError)): ?>
                <span class="help-inline"><?php echo $onNotesError; ?></span>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function()
{
    $('#addNoteForm').validate
    ({
        rules:
        {
               onNotes: "required"
        },

        messages: 
        {
              onNotes: "bdfbdfghdfge!"
        },

        submitHandler: function(form)
        {
             form.submit();
        }
    });
});
```

I have included the relevant `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js` in my header, after `"text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js`.

Yes, both are within script tags and come after the `src` attribute.

Note that this `form` element is inside a Bootstrap modal.

**Edit**: console reports 0 errors

Comment: "I am having trouble validating my form"... what exactly is the trouble? Are there any errors? Is some output different than what you expect?

Comment: I don' see this element `AddNoteForm`

Comment: Maybe `$('[name="AddNoteForm"]')` should be `$('[name="addNoteForm"]')` or `$('#addNoteForm')`?

Comment: Sorry my bad. I would like to add that I am using $('#addNoteForm') as the selector already, and it still doesnt work

Comment: Also, my console reports no errors

Comment: Have you tried to remove attribute *onsubmit="$('#addNoteForm').validate();"*?

Comment: Yes, I have. That was added after, as an attempted fix. I will remove it from the question.